# Patent in two different countries; two patents or one?

Tags: patentability, international

One patent I have as inventor my institution issued first in Europe, and later in the United States; can I then say that I have two patents or just one?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a patent in Europe and one in the United States, you *do* have two patents. That's how the patent system works.

Beyond that, the question just becomes what "can I then say" means. If you're speaking in the legal sense, it's more or less indisputable that you have two separate patents. On the other hand, if you're speaking in the *marketing* sense, that's a little more subjective. I would probably stick to saying "I have an invention patented in two countries," just since "I have two patents" is, while accurate, fairly misleading. Ultimately, it's just a matter of context. But I'd generally side on the more verbose, less misleading phrasing.

Comment: thanks for your insightful comment! I would like to know whether from the academic point of view, i.e., for the CV, it is counts twice too

Comment: @flow Again, "it counts" is subjective. If it were me, I would, as I said, probably go with "an invention patented in two jurisdictions." I imagine the last thing you want is for someone to read this, think you have two inventions, look you up, and think you lied or intentionally misled them.

Comment: I have a fair number of patents which were issued in the United States and other countries.  Because all of my patents started life in the US, I only ever give my US patent count.  What I say in my resume and elsewhere is "I have 40-something (I forget the number ...) patents issued in the US and elsewhere."  That's the most honest and shows that the patents were worth protecting outside the US patent system.